# How to post a comment using Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, http-post, facebook-comments

I'm trying to post a comment to my facebook using facebook API.
I'm trying to send this request:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{post id}/comments/?access_token={token}&message=hello
```

This return to me list of comments but doesn't post the message I sent.
What should I do to post my message?

Thanks.

Comment: You should make it an actual POST request … because it sounds like you have been using GET so far.

Answer (score 4):

You should make a POST request and make sure you have all the permissions required to publish. Docs [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/object/comments#publish).

Answer (score 4):

**Update**

> As of April 24,2018, the publish_actions permission has been removed. Please see the [Breaking Changes Changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#login-4-24) for more details. To provide a way for your app users to share content to Facebook, we encourage you to use our [Sharing products](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing) instead.

Comment: facebook's graph api used to be so nice. Now is only for page stuff basically